# Opencv Manager hardware not detected

Tags: android, opencv, hardware

I've tried running the samples from OpenCV and after it prompts for the OpenCV Manager package, I click ok for the installer from the Play Store and it says item not found. If I try to install OpenCV Manager manually, it says Hardware not detected and the samples don't work because of this. If I get from the cmd the platform name it says: armeabi v7a.And there is a version for this platform for the OpenCV Manager so why can't it detect the hardware.?

Comment: Perhaps you can rephrase your question to be more clear and specific?

Comment: Which part isn't clear enough? @Urahara